# How to solve single quotes error in csv file import?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have problem when importing csv file that contain single quote. In my csv file, some data with single quote(**apostrophe**) like this.

```
"User's answer","answer one","answer two","answer three".
```

I use comma(,) to separate columns in my csv.
When I try to import that data into database, it show error. Here is my code.

```
while(($data=fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) != FALSE ){
    $id = $data[0];
    $name = $data[1];//User's name
    $sql = "UPDATE my_table SET name='$name' WHERE id='$id'";
    mysql_db_query($dbname, $sql)or die("update error".mysql_error());
}
```

The above code show sql syntax error. if I remove single quote(') from csv file and import, everything is ok. But some data may contain single quote(') in the future. So, I add `mysql_real_escape_string` to `$name` like this

```
while(($data=fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) != FALSE ){
        $id = $data[0];
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($data[1]);//User's name
        $sql = "UPDATE my_table SET name='$name' WHERE id='$id'";
        mysql_db_query($dbname, $sql)or die("update error".mysql_error());
    }
```

But, it import into database below I show.

```
'User''s answer'
```

It is wrong because I want to save just like `User's answer`. I don't know why it saves a lot of single quotes. Please give me advice how can I solve it.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: why don't you use MySQL LOAD DATA? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html it will be a little tricky because you don't have to just import a csv file but also update, but it's better than parsing the file by code - also, use prepared statements

Comment: When I use **addslashes** instead of **mysql_real_escape_string**, it shows the same error like this `'User''s answer'`. Thank you.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a string, you can create a stream that wraps it and then use it [see here](http://code.google.com/p/phpstringstream/source/browse/trunk/stringstream.php). A class which used to parse csv strings.

In PHP there is also a function kown as [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). But I have faced some issues with it.